# How can change route on submit event in React with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I use React with TypeScript, I want simply when on submit button click, change route to specific state.

`this.props.router.push('/list');` not work on submit method.

React versions:

```
"react": "15.5.4",
"react-dom": "15.5.4",
```

My Code in tsx file

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

export interface CreateProps {
    router?: BrowserRouter;
}

export class Create extends React.Component<CreateProps, {}> {

    constructor(props: CreateProps) {

        super(props);
    }

    public render() {
        return <div>
            <h1>Create</h1>
            <form className="WelcomeForm">
                <input name="Date" />
                <button onClick={() => { this.submit() }}>Save</button>
            </form>
        </div>;
    }

    submit() {
        this.props.router.push('/list');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have access by props to *objects* below:

- `history`
- `location`
- `match`

source: [Philosophy - react-router documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy)

In your case you should use [`history`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history) object to change the path, not router because such prop doesn't exist.

```
this.props.history.push('/list');
```

Comment: I used your suggested code but throw this error TS2339: Property 'history' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<CreateProps>'

Comment: So it means that it's not the component that is passed to the `<Route />`. You have to wrap your `class Create...` code with `withRouter` function from `react-router-dom`. You can see sample code in official react-router documentation https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

Answer (score 0):

```
  contextTypes: {
    router: React.PropTypes.object
  }


  submit(event) {
    this.context.router.push('/list')
  }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.